# Difficulty Applying Conditional Rendering to Multiple Array Items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

I am trying to set up a quiz questions page (using an API) where, if you select the correct answer for the specific question, the text will show green and the score will increment by one and, if the incorrect answer is selected, the text will show red and the score will remain unchanged.

I am able to apply the logic if there is only one question but, when trying to apply it to ten questions, it applies the changes to each question.

Please see the console and application screenshots below:

- For one question:

[image: Screenshot - One question]

- For ten questions:

[image: Screenshot - Ten Questions]

My code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "../App.css";
import { Row, Col, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const Questionnaire = () => {
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");
  const [style, setStyle] = useState("");
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  const location = useLocation();
  const quiz = location.state.quiz;

  // Added:_______________________________//
  const answerOptions = {
    a: "answer_a",
    b: "answer_b",
    c: "answer_c",
    d: "answer_d",
    e: "answer_e",
    f: "answer_f",
  };

  const answerOptionsArray = Array.from(
    { length: quiz.length },
    () => answerOptions
  );

  const questionIndex = Array.from({ length: quiz.length }, (_, i) => i + 1);

  const masterData = questionIndex.map((index, i) => {
    return {
      questionIndex: index,
      answerOptions: answerOptionsArray[i],
      quiz: quiz[i],
    };
  });

  const setAnswer = (e) => {
    const optionValues = answerOptionsArray.map((option) => Object.values(option.a))
    const optionExists = Object.values(answerOptionsArray).includes("answer_a");

    if (optionExists == true) {
      setSelectedAnswer(e.target.value);
    }
    console.log(optionValues);
    // Returns: [ 'answer_a', 'answer_b', 'answer_c', 'answer_d', 'answer_e', 'answer_f' ]
    console.log(e.target.value);
    // Returns: answer_a (If button with "answer_a" is clicked on).
    console.log(optionExists);
    // Returns: false
    console.log(selectedAnswer);
    // Returns: Empty log
  };
  //______________________________________//

  const checkAnswers = (e) => {
    const correctAnswers = masterData.map(
      (answer) => answer.quiz.correct_answers
    );

    const answerCheckA = correctAnswers.map(
      (answer) => answer.answer_a_correct
    );
    const answerCheckB = correctAnswers.map(
      (answer) => answer.answer_b_correct
    );
    const answerCheckC = correctAnswers.map(
      (answer) => answer.answer_c_correct
    );
    const answerCheckD = correctAnswers.map(
      (answer) => answer.answer_d_correct
    );
    const answerCheckE = correctAnswers.map(
      (answer) => answer.answer_e_correct
    );
    const answerCheckF = correctAnswers.map(
      (answer) => answer.answer_f_correct
    );

    if (answerCheckA == "true" && selectedAnswer == "answer_a") {
      setStyle("correct-answer");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (answerCheckB == "true" && selectedAnswer == "answer_b") {
      setStyle("correct-answer");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (answerCheckC == "true" && selectedAnswer == "answer_c") {
      setStyle("correct-answer");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (answerCheckD == "true" && selectedAnswer == "answer_d") {
      setStyle("correct-answer");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (answerCheckE == "true" && selectedAnswer == "answer_e") {
      setStyle("correct-answer");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (answerCheckF == "true" && selectedAnswer == "answer_f") {
      setStyle("correct-answer");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else {
      setStyle("incorrect-answer");
      setScore(score);
    }
    console.log("Score: " + score);
  };

  // Adjusted buttons to accommodate the above changes and moved "checkAnswers()" button to the bottom.

  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <h3 className="quiz-component-header">
            Quiz: {quiz[0].category} &#10088; {quiz[0].difficulty} &#10089;
          </h3>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      {Object.values(masterData).length !== 0 ? (
        <div>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              {masterData.map((content, i) => (
                <Card
                  key={i}
                  className="col-md-11 question-card"
                  content={content}
                >
                  <Card.Title>QUESTION {content.questionIndex}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Text>{content.quiz.question}</Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>SELECT YOUR ANSWER</Card.Title>
                  {content.quiz.answers.answer_a !== null ? (
                    <Button
                      value="answer_a"
                      onClick={(e) => setAnswer(e)}
                      className={
                        selectedAnswer === "answer_a" ? style : undefined
                      }
                    >
                      a. {content.quiz.answers.answer_a}
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <div></div>
                  )}
                  {content.quiz.answers.answer_b !== null ? (
                    <Button
                      value="answer_b"
                      onClick={(e) => setAnswer(e)}
                      className={
                        selectedAnswer === "answer_b" ? style : undefined
                      }
                    >
                      b. {content.quiz.answers.answer_b}
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <div></div>
                  )}
                  {content.quiz.answers.answer_c !== null ? (
                    <Button
                      value="answer_c"
                      onClick={(e) => setAnswer(e)}
                      className={
                        selectedAnswer === "answer_c" ? style : undefined
                      }
                    >
                      c. {content.quiz.answers.answer_c}
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <div></div>
                  )}
                  {content.quiz.answers.answer_d !== null ? (
                    <Button
                      value="answer_d"
                      onClick={(e) => setAnswer(e)}
                      className={
                        selectedAnswer === "answer_d" ? style : undefined
                      }
                    >
                      d. {content.quiz.answers.answer_d}
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <div></div>
                  )}
                  {content.quiz.answers.answer_e !== null ? (
                    <Button
                      value="answer_e"
                      onClick={(e) => setAnswer(e)}
                      className={
                        selectedAnswer === "answer_e" ? style : undefined
                      }
                    >
                      e. {content.quiz.answers.answer_e}
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <div></div>
                  )}
                  {content.quiz.answers.answer_f !== null ? (
                    <Button
                      value="answer_f"
                      onClick={(e) => setAnswer(e)}
                      className={
                        selectedAnswer === "answer_f" ? style : undefined
                      }
                    >
                      f. {content.quiz.answers.answer_f}
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <div></div>
                  )}
                </Card>
              ))}
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Button type="submit" onClick={checkAnswers}>
            Check Score
          </Button>
          <h3>Score: {score} / 10</h3>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h3>There are Currently No Questions For Your Query</h3>
          <h4>Watch This Space For Added Questions</h4>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Questionnaire;
```

Please may someone assist? I would appreciate any help that anyone is willing to offer.

Comment: At this point in the code: `quiz.map((content, i) =>`, it is observed that all questions (at `content.question` are rendered. So, whatever is within the `()` after the `=>` will be rendered 10 times (if there are 10 questions). However, there is only 1 `selectedAnswer` which is common for all 10 questions. Hence, each of the 10 answers get updated when `selectedAnswer` is updated.

Comment: Make `selectedAnswer` an object where the key is the question number and the value is the correct-answer for the specific question number. Please let us know if that helps progress further.

Comment: @jsN00b Apologies for the delayed response. Thank you so much for your advice. It makes sense to render it the same amount of times in order to get separate outcomes. I tried implementing something similar to what you have suggested, but am unfortunately not having much success. I am not sure whether this is in line with what you had in mind or if I am doing something wrong? I have updated the question's code to include the added code.

Answer (score 0):

This may be one possible approach / method to try resolving the issue described in the question.

The below is not a working example. It is merely an approach.

```
const Questionnaire = () => {
  .
  .
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState({});
  .
  .
  const [style, setStyle] = useState({});
  .
  .
  const setAnswerForQuestion = (qIdx, answerKey) => {
    setSelectedAnswer(prev => ({...prev, [qIdx]: answerKey}));
  };
  .
  .
  const checkAnswers = () => {
    const correctAnswers = quiz[0].correct_answers; // quiz[0] only
    // see <h3 className="quiz-component-header">
    // only quiz[0] is rendered in this component
    const tempScore = correctAnswers.reduce((total, ans, qIdx) => (
      total + ( ans === selectedAnswers[qIdx] ? 1 || 0)
    ), 0);
    setScore(tempScore);
    // Now, set style for each question's answer
    setStyle(correctAnswers.reduce((fin, ans, qIdx) => ({
      ...fin,
      [qIdx]: 
        ans === selectedAnswers[qIdx]
          ? 'correct-answer'
          : 'incorrect-answer'
    }), {}));
  };
  .
  .
  .
  return (
    .
    .
    {masterData.map((content, i) => (
      <Card key={i} className="col-md-11 question-card" content={content}>
        <Card.Title>QUESTION {content.questionIndex}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Text>{content.quiz.question}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>SELECT YOUR ANSWER</Card.Title>
        { Object.entries(content.quiz.answers).map(([k, v], aIdx) => (
            v !== null &&
            <Button
              value={k}
              className={style[i] || undefined}
              onClick={() => setAnswerForQuestion(i, k)}
            >
              {String.fromCharCode(97 + aIdx)}. {v}
            </Button>
          ))
        }
        
        .
        .
        .
      </Card>
      .
      .
      .
      <Button type="submit" onClick={checkAnswers}>
        Check Score
      </Button>
      <h3>Score: {score} / 10</h3>
      .
      .
    )}
    .
    .
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @jsNoob. Thank you so much for providing me with an alternative method/ approach. It is much appreciated. I have started experimenting with this, but have not had the opportunity to look into this further. Apologies for the delayed responses. I have started as a Junior Developer, my first development job, on the 14th of February. I hope to take a look at this again as soon as possible.